# Definition of the Limes Superior

Tags: real-analysis

I understand what the limes superior is insofar as I know that for example for an alternating series as $a_n = (-1)^n$ which does not diverge to $\infty$, we can define the bigger accumulation point 1 as the limes superior.

What I don't understand yet though is the corresponding notation which is:

$\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \ \inf_{k \geq n} x_k$

I understand this so far as follows:

1. I pick one concrete $n \in \mathbb N$, say n = 3.
2. Then I pick the infimum of the set $\{x_3,x_4,.....x_{1000},...\}$, lets call this infimum $\inf_3$
3. Next I set n = 4. And pick the infimum of the set $\{x_4,x_5,....\}$ etc.

Naturally this sequence of infima must be monotonically falling (each set of we take the infimum of is a subset of the previous set). So, of what exactly are we then taking the Supremum of? I.e. where is my understanding wrong, since such as I understand it obviously is not making much sense...thanks

Comment: The sequence of infima is increasing!

Comment: Ah, you are right of course..and so everything I wrote then is correct and of this increasing sequence we take the supremum?

Comment: @TestGuest: indeed, this is the case - you consider a sequence of infimas of tails (which is non-decreasing), and $\limsup$ is a limit ($=\sup$) of this sequence.

Comment: What I written above I am realizing now is not the limes superior at all - but the limes inferior!!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is monotonically **not decreasing**, actually. Think at the sequence $(2 - 1/n)$; for $n=1$ the inf is 1, for $n=2$ is 3/2, and so on.

Comment: and so of this increasing sequence we take the supremum..? is the rest of my understanding correct?

Comment: yes. The lim sup is by definition the lowest value which is greater of, or equal, to every element of the sequence. The trick of finding out a non-decreasing sequence is useful so that you have a monotone sequence, and therefore the lim sup is just the supremum.

Comment: Why don't we simply take the supremum of {$x_1,x_2,..$} instead of taking the supremum of the infima?

Comment: @mau: That's the supremum of the sequence, not the lim sup.  For example, consider the sequence $1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots$ whose supremum is 1 but whose limsup is 0.

Comment: I stand corrected. (I fear I have to study basic analysis again)